# Automatic logout from WordPress after leaving protected area

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I have a wordpress site and I need the function so if your logged into a protected page and you leave that page you cannot hit the back button and go back without signing in again.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Well the admin area is always at /wp-admin and id imagine it uses session authentication so why don't you just put a piece of code into your index file, or any other file that gets called on each page load that deletes the session if the url doesn't begin with /wp-admin
For example:

```
if(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 9)!='/wp-admin') {
    session_destroy();
}
```

Comment: Iv had a look and wordpress knows if your logged in because of cookies that are set. Do you know how to look at what cookies have been set? You could then alter the code so that instead of session_destroy() it deletes the appropriate cookie(s)